# ASP.NET "Keep Me Logged In" not working on one computer

Tags: asp.net, login-control

I have an ASP.NET site that uses a standard, wizard created login control. I have made no changes to it.

Logon works fine, however, one one single computer the Keep Me Logged On doesn't work, it forces me to log on every time I restart the browser. This happens only on one computer (works fine on three others), and it only happens in Internet Explorer (version 8.0, works as it should in Firefox.)

I assume it is some configuration setting in IE, but I have searched and searched to no avail. Anyone got a suggestion for me?

Comment: Are cookies turned off on this particular browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That browser is probably [deleting all its cookies on exit](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Microsoft-Internet-Explorer-1054/Setting-Internet-Explorer-delete.htm).